# SP Masterpage not reflecting changes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to change the masterpage that one of my wikipages is using in SharePoint 2010.  I need to change xua from ie8 to ie10
Below were the steps I took.

*Created a copy of master page and called it "dbCustom.master"
*Add the following line "" in the page
*Change the directive to point to the custom masterpage <@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/dbCustom.master"..../>

Two things
First: After saving all my changes, xua stayed as ie8
Second: The page showed a yellow strip with the following text: "The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template. "  As you can see from the image below, changes are not reflected.
[image]

Also, in my SharePoint Designer Settings, I have enabled "Enable Customzing Master Pages and Page Layouts" but my changes are still not being reflected.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the yeloow message

> The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to
>   template

This error comes up in page when a page is customized.

**For example:** you have created a page mypage.aspx with master page `‘default.master’`. Now if you change the master page to `custom.master` then you will find the message `‘The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template’`.

If you make any change to the page then the page will be customized and you will find a message. Till now there are no known settings to stop the message. but you can hide it via CSS as mentioned at

- ["The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116074/the-current-page-has-been-customized-from-its-template-revert-to-template)
- [The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-current-page-has-been.html)

**Regarding your changes is not reflected**, some points need to check.

- Make sure you have applied the changes to the correct master page file.
- Make sure you have checked out the file and edit it in advanced mode.
- After you have finished your changing, make sure that you save your file > check in > publish as a major version.
- During browsing the page , try to remove cahch by clicking on ctrl+ f5.

Comment: I have followed your steps but I don't get prompted to publish as a major version.  It just allows me to check in the file and the page still does not reflect my changes.